# Listing installed packages using apt list --installed, but only display the package names

Tags: command-line, apt, bash, scripts

I use bash a lot and I was working on a script that I could use to help someone uninstall a package, and in the error message that shows when the package is not on the system, I am trying to figure out how to display a list of all installed packages, like `apt list --installed` does, but without all the information (for example: without `/jammy,now 1.4.8+dfsg-3build1 amd64 [installed,automatic]`), but just display the package names. Here is the command that I tried to display the packages without the extra info from my code:

```
apt list --installed | grep -oP '/jammy \K.*' |  grep -o "$removepackagename" | awk -F'|' 'NR==1 {print;x=$2} NR>1 {if ($2 != x) {print;x=$2}}'
```

I hoped that my command above would show me the list of packages that was installed without the extra info. Also, In the command above, I tried channeling my knowledge of grep (which is pretty much 0) to remove the extra info, and that part of the command is:

```
grep -oP '/jammy \K.*'
```

I also wanted the output to be something like:

```
apt
aptitude
(some other packages on new lines each)
```

(I also know that that is not what it actually will output, this is just a example.)

Comment: Please add your desired output to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To list only the names of all installed packages:

```
apt list --installed | cut -d'/' -f1 | uniq
```

To list the names of all installed packages only one screen at a time to make it easier to scroll through the results:

```
apt list --installed | cut -d'/' -f1 | uniq | less
```

To save a list of the names of all installed packages in a file named installed-packages.txt

```
apt list --installed | cut -d'/' -f1 | uniq > installed-packages.txt
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I will use this in my project. For some reason I never thought to use awk!

Comment: @Quasímodo Thanks for commenting. I edited my answer so that the output no longer includes those unwanted package architecture suffixes.